# Jquery - Open .next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a script that only opens the next div called .video-overlay. 
I do not want to use ID's as there could be up to 30 videos per page.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2fqrzbw/

At the moment the script is affecting both... is there a way of targetting the next div named .video-overlay?

HTML:

```
<span class="video-trigger">Button 1 </span>
<!-- Close video trigger-->

<div class="video-overlay">
    <div class="overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="container">
      Popup 1
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Close video popup-->


<br><br/>
<br><br/>
<br><br/>



<span class="video-trigger">Button 2</span>
<!-- Close video trigger-->

<div class="video-overlay">
    <div class="overlay-close">Close</div>
    <div class="container">
      Popup 2
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Close video popup-->
```

JS:

```
//Video popup
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.video-trigger').click(function() {
            $('.video-overlay').fadeIn(300);
            $('.video-overlay video').get(0).play();

        });
        $('.video-overlay .overlay-close').click(function() {
            $('.video-overlay').fadeOut(300);
            $('.video-overlay video').get(0).pause();
        });
    });
```

This is how it is laid out in my actual web document:

```
<div class="col span_6_of_12 ripple-me">
                            <div class="video-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $video_thumbnail; ?>);">
                                <span class="video-trigger">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!--Close Video box cta -->

                            <div class="video-overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-close">Close</div>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <iframe allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen' src="<?php echo $video_link; ?>" width="960" height="370" allowtransparency="true" style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;' frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Close video popup-->

                        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with this: `<br><br/>`. `<br>` does not have a closing tag and does not use a closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current logic is that it's affecting all `.video-overlay` elements on click. To fix this you can use DOM traversal to find only the one related to the clicked `.video-trigger` using `next()` and `closest()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.video-overlay').fadeIn(300).find('video').get(0).play();
  });

  $('.video-overlay .overlay-close').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.video-overlay').fadeOut(300).find('video').get(0).pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: The video is a little further down the page, but still is next in line.. This did not launch the window

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JQuery Next Function](https://api.jquery.com/next/) :

```
//Video popup
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.video-trigger').click(function() {
        var $videoOverlay = $(this).next('.video-overlay');
        videoOverlay.fadeIn(300);
        videoOverlay.find('video').get(0).play();

    });
});
```

Comment: Note that `.overlay-close` has no `.video-overlay` sibling, so `next()` won't work for that case

Comment: That's right. Use `closest` before `next` in this case

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides powerful DOM traversal tools. Be sure to use them

```
//Video popup
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.video-overlay').fadeIn(300);
    $('.video-overlay video').get(0).play();

  });
  $('.video-overlay .overlay-close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
    $('.video-overlay video').get(0).pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: That'll be because after you added context, your span is no longer a sibling of the video-overlay div. Try this instead https://jsfiddle.net/Strid3r/w2fqrzbw/3/